# Has a theorem of number theory been proven by first using an unresolved conjecture, and second using the negation of that unresolved conjecture?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, proof-writing, foundations

It's well-known that given a sentence independent of a system of axioms, we can consistently extend the system by appending either the sentence or its negation.  However, if a given theorem can be deduced in each of the two systems, then we have a proof of that theorem.  We don't even need to prove independence, because given any sentence, either it or its negation is consistent with a given system, provided that the original axiom system is consistent.

I'm simply wondering whether there's a specific example of that proof technique having been used.

Comment: [See MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333157/arriving-at-the-same-result-with-the-opposite-hypotheses)